# Rigorous proof of Bolzano-Weirstrass theorem for sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Revisiting some elementary proofs I'm trying to write them as rigorously as posible so I've tried it for Bolzano-Weierstrass' theorem for sequences, and it would be really helpful if you could tell me if the proof is completely correct, if the induction I've made is correct and if I'm using some axioms (such as choice axiom or something in that way) without noticing it.

Thank you very, very much for your answers.

**Theorem**: Let $\{a_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ be a bounded real sequence, $L^+=\limsup\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n$ and $L^-=\liminf\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n$, then $L^+$ and $L^-$ are limit points of $a_n$ and, for every other limit point $x$, we have that $L^- \leq x \leq L^+$.

Defining $a_N^+=\sup \{a_n: n \geq N\}$, $a_N^-=\inf \{a_n: n \geq N\}$, we have that

$L^+=\lim\limits_{N\to\infty} a_N^+$

$L^-=\lim\limits_{N\to\infty} a_N^-$

In first place, if $x$ is a limit point, then there exists a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}_{k \geq 1}$ of $\{a_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ such that converges to $x$ and as we have the relation

$a_{n_k}^-=\inf \{a_n: n \geq n_k\} \leq a_{n_k} \leq \sup \{a_n: n \geq n_k\}=a_{n_k}^+$

Taking limits (any subsequence of $\{a_N^+\}$ and $\{a_N^-\}$ converges due they are convergent) we get that $L^- \leq x \leq L^+$ as we wanted.

Now, we'll proof that $L^-$ is a limit point i.e., that exists a subsequence of $\{a_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ such that it converges to $L^-$ (proving it for $L^+$ is analogous).

We'll proof then that for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$ exists a chain of sets

$A_0 \supset A_1 \supset \cdots \supset A_k \supset \{a_n: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$

such that $A_0=\emptyset$ and

$A_j=\{a_{n_1}, \cdots, a_{n_j}\} \subset \{a_n: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$

so that $n_1 < n_2 < \cdots < n_j$ and $a_{n_i}^- \leq a_{n_i} \leq a_{n_i}^- + \frac{1}{i}$ for every $i=1, \cdots, j$.

Then, we could define the subsequence of $\{a_n\}_{n \geq 1}$

$\{a_{n_k}\}_{k \geq 1}=\{(k,r) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{R}: r \in A_k \setminus A_{k-1}\}$

and due to the relation $a_{n_k}^- \leq a_{n_k} \leq a_{n_k}^- + \frac{1}{k}$ by the squeeze theorem we get that $\{a_{n_k}\}_{k \geq 1}$ converges to $L^-$ as we wanted to proof.

All said, lets proof the existance of the sets $A_k$ by induction.

If $k=1$, as $a_1^-+1$ is not a lower bound of $\{a_n:n \geq 1\}$ there exists an $a_{n_1} \in \{a_n: n \geq 1\}$ such that $a_{n_1}^- \leq a_{n_1} \leq a_1^-+1 \leq a_{n_1}^-+1$ so it suffices to define $A_1=\{a_{n_1}\}$.

Now, suppose that there exist the chain $A_1 \supset A_2 \supset \cdots \supset A_k$ in the way descibed before, and lets see we can construct the set $A_{k+1}$ as wanted.

We have that $a_{n_k+1}^- + \frac{1}{k+1}$ is not a lower bound of $\{a_n:n \geq n_k+1\}$ and therefore there exits $a_{n_{k+1}} \in \{a_n: n \geq n_k+1\}$ such that $a_{n_{k+1}}^- \leq  a_{n_{k+1}} \leq a_{n_k+1}^- + \frac{1}{k+1} \leq a_{n_{k+1}}^- + \frac{1}{k+1}$, so defining $A_{k+1}=A_k \cup \{a_{n_{k+1}}\}$ we conclude the induction and the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is basically correct (though you should reverse the inclusions of $A_i$, so that $A_1\subset A_2\subset A_3\subset\dots$).
However, introducing these sets $A_i$ is not necessary: if $a_{n_k}$ is already given, then your method will find an $a_{n_{k+1}}$ so that $a^-_{n_k}\le a_{n_{k+1}}\le a^-_{n_k}+\frac1k$.

No axiom of choice is involved here, only induction on $k$ to construct the desired subsequence.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take the comment ;)